# Vue JS Modal doesn't show correctly a DateTimePicker component inside him

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue for a web app. I'm also using a [modal package](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal) and inside him I'm putting a [bootstrap date time picker](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker) component. But the result looks pretty ugly.

It looks like this:

[image]

Apparently Vue 'cuts' the content that is outside a component.

I don't know if this is a Vue problem or simply a matter of css.

Comment: there's a conflict inside your css when using these two components

Comment: thanks for answering, I'm using the default css for these components. It has also happened to me with other components. 
Is there any style that overwrites the default and fix this?